# identifying the most recent datetime

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm having some trouble with logic I need to produce `df$val_most_recent`.  If there's a value for both `a_val` and `b_val`, `val_most_recent` should be the value with the most recent time (`a_val` corresponds to`a_dtm`, `b_val` corresponds to`b_dtm`). If the times are identical, I'd like `a_val` to be `val_most_recent`. If just one value is reported for the two (with the other being a `NA`, it should simply be that one.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

location <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
a_dtm <- ymd_hm(c(NA, "2019-06-05 10:30", "2019-06-05 10:45", "2019-06-05 10:50"))
b_dtm <- ymd_hm(c("2019-06-05 10:30", NA,  "2019-06-05 10:48", "2019-06-05 10:50"))
a_val <- c(NA, 6, 4, 2)
b_val <- c(5, NA, 3, 2)

df <- data.frame(location, a_dtm, b_dtm, a_val, b_val)

as_tibble(df)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#location a_dtm               b_dtm               a_val b_val
#<fct>    <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a        NA                  2019-06-05 10:30:00    NA     5
#2 b        2019-06-05 10:30:00 NA                      6    NA
#3 c        2019-06-05 10:45:00 2019-06-05 10:48:00     4     3
#4 d        2019-06-05 10:50:00 2019-06-05 10:50:00     2     2

val_most_recent <- c(5,6,3,2)
desired_df <- cbind(df, val_most_recent)
as_tibble(desired_df)

#location a_dtm               b_dtm                  a_val    b_val val_most_recent
#<fct>    <dttm>              <dttm>                 <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 a        NA                  2019-06-05 10:30:00    NA     5           5
#2 b        2019-06-05 10:30:00 NA                      6    NA           6
#3 c        2019-06-05 10:45:00 2019-06-05 10:48:00     4     3           3
#4 d        2019-06-05 10:50:00 2019-06-05 10:50:00     2     2           2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic from your text coded into a `case_when` statement:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    val_most_recent = case_when(
      is.na(a_val) | is.na(b_va) ~ coalesce(a_val, b_val),
      a_dtm >= b_dtm ~ a_val,
      TRUE ~ b_val
    )
  )
#   location               a_dtm               b_dtm a_val b_val val_most_recent
# 1        a                <NA> 2019-06-05 10:30:00    NA     5               5
# 2        b 2019-06-05 10:30:00                <NA>     6    NA               6
# 3        c 2019-06-05 10:45:00 2019-06-05 10:48:00     4     3               3
# 4        d 2019-06-05 10:50:00 2019-06-05 10:50:00     2     2               2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option in `base R`, convert the dates to numeric, replace the `NAs` with 0, get the column index with the max values in each row, `cbind` with the row index and extract the corresponding values from 'a_val/b_val' column

```
m1 <- sapply(df[2:3], as.numeric)
df$val_most_recent <- df[4:5][cbind(seq_len(nrow(m1)), 
         max.col(replace(m1, is.na(m1), 0), "first"))]
df$val_most_recent
#[1] 5 6 3 2
```